# Get current Date and time on frontend

Tags: magento2, timezone

**Problem:**
After a long time of research, I have stuck to find it's the solution
I applied the following code but it didn't work.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
 $date = $objDate->gmtDate();
```

Any help.
your help would be appreciated!

**Version:**
Magento 2.4.4

Answer (score 3):

It's 2 general ways:

```php
// current time or any time in UTC
$now = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// instances
$timezone = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface::class);
$locale   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class)
    ->getLocale();

// example in custom format
$localeDate = $timezone->date(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')), $locale);
echo $localeDate->format('m/d/y H:i:s');

// example with format from locale 
echo $timezone->formatDateTime(
    $now,
    \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM
);
```

Output:

```
06/06/22 12:12:03
6/6/22, 12:12:03 PM
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but these two method is not getting date from TimeZone in store's configuration as like time.
getting date from my system clock.

Comment: change you time in system's clock then check it getting date from your system.

Comment: What is timezone set in configuration? Global/Store. What is scope?
FE I have system time +3 and Magento -8 and getting correct date/time like all other in Magento. It's the logic which used in Magento

Answer (score 2):

Use below code.

```
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
class Yourclass extends AbstractClass
{
    protected $timezoneInterface;

    public function __construct(
        ...
     TimezoneInterface $timezoneInterface
     )
    {
        $this->timezoneInterface = $timezoneInterface;
         ...
    }

    public function getStoreDateTime()
    {
        $formatDate = $this->timezoneInterface->formatDate();        
        $dateTime = $this->timezoneInterface->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $date = $this->timezoneInterface->date()->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $this->timezoneInterface->date()->format('H:i');
        
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://webkul.com/blog/save-and-get-date-time-according-to-time-zone-in-magento2/)

Comment: time shows correctly but the date is showing by my system, not for the time zone location that are I set in store configuration.

Comment: I want to fetch date from configure time zone area.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$timezone = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');
$today = $timezone->date()->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
$dateTimeAsTimeZone = $timezone->date(new \DateTime($dateTime))->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
```

Comment: time shows correctly but the date is showing by my system, not for the time zone location that are I set in store configuration.

Comment: I want to fetch date from configure time zone area.